# Coredata entity relationship with itself with rules

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

To understand a lot of core data, I'm working to all sorts of likely scenarios to develop a scalable model, to secure future.. in a way..

Among that I have a situation, there are many ways to do it, i was looking for a most efficient way.

What I'm working on:

ControllerEntity   {
title: String;
**Relationship**: Parent (to-many)
}

ParentEntity   {
title: String;
**Relationship**: Child (to-many)
**Relationship**: Controller (to-one)

}

ChildEntity   {
Value: NSNumber;
**Relationship**: Parent (to-one; inverse)
}

Now please consider these random formulae..

```
A (parentEntity) =  Alpha (child) + Beta (child) + Gamma (child)
B (parentEntity) =  Pi (child)    + Gamma (child) + Beta (child)
```

Having A and B as parent Objects and adding these objects were no problem at all with their respective Child sets,
*Worth noting is that, Beta child exists in both Parent entities.*

heres the change:

```
Gamma (child) = [Alpha (child) + Beta (child)] / 2
```

Both Alpha and Beta child objects are the same in both entities, hence there can ONLY BE ONE!

It seemed pretty easy to just ad Gamma as a PARENT and add those two as their child and compute. But that (though was the easy way out) wasn't good for the future proofing.. too many objects is always a bad idea..

Hence, i wanted to find a relationship that a ChildEntity would have ... with kinda itself(if it can). For example a **Child** entity of **Gamma** would get its value automatically deriving from **Alpha** child and **Beta** child.

There are certain conditions that all these relationships should satisfy:

1. One Controller Object can Have ONLY ONE "*TYPE*" of **Child** Object. There can be many **Parent** objects for it. For example, if the Controller has created a Parent **A**, he could add **Alpha** and **Beta** Child, when the same controller creates Parent **B**, he can add New Pi child but not Beta as it already exists, he should "choose" it.. i could add some kinda identifier unique per child. How can i set a rule to accomplish this on NewInsert.
2. How could a child have a relationship with itself? in such a way that :
3. - Parent should can Have ONE ONE **Gamma** child Which intern calculates its value based on values from Child Alpha and CHild Beta, which are, again, Unique per Controller.
4. heres an model i created, but I don't really know how would i add a
   Child (alpha) and CHild (Beta) as subchilds of Child Gamma!
5. When Quering ParentA.childs that should reveal only 3 child objects - Alpha, Beta, Gamma.
6. ParentB.Childs should reveal --->> Pi, Gamma, Beta, (3 objects).
7. If i chose to reveal all childs of a parent with out childs having subchilds,
8. - Parent A should have oNLY 2 - Alpha and Beta

     - Parent B should have 3 -> Pi, Alpha, Beta.
9. Lastly when i decide to export or convert this data into xml, it shouldn't be as confusing..

[image]

As someone new to core data I'm finding it difficult to go away form sqlite kinda thinking, but I'm trying.

Any help is appreciated